# Add close option to Jquery Color Picker

Tags: jquery

Im using the color picker here: http://blog.meta100.com/post/600571131/mcolorpicker

Im using code shown in example 3.

What I want to do is allow the user to close the colorPicker DIV if they choose not to pick a colour.

I managed to add a close link in the top left corner and add a jquery.css command to display: none the div which does hide it fine. However, you will notice fron example 3 if you click the square (which is pink) to show the colour picker, hover inside the ipcker you will see the square changes to the color under your mouse.  If you then hover out of the DIV it default to white.  What I need it to do is default back to its original colour.

When I click my added close button it also defaults back to white which isnt good for me.

Anyone have any idea how I can alter the .js file supplied with this picker so it will go back to its starting colour if you hover out of the div or close it?

Sorry for the long winded explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creator of the colorpicker helped and fixed the things I needed.

http://blog.meta100.com/post/600571131/mcolorpicker